# Having work and student permit simultaneously in 2 EU countries

Tags: resident-permit, work-permit

I am a ***third-country*** national and I have a **student permit** in Hungary. I also have a work permit in Finland only for **3 months in the summer**. Am I alright to extend my student permit to Hungary as I have to come back in September? **Are we allowed to have both student and work permits simultaneously in 2 different EU countries**?

Comment: When does your current student permit expire?

Comment: current june 31st , the work permit starts in 1st of June and ends in September

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with this, but I can't point to anything that would confirm my belief, so I can't really post a proper answer.